Provisional Headers are shown - solved but I don't know why exactly?
I am using useQuery to handle my API requests and ran to this error when I was trying to handle two GET requests in one functional component, I tried other people’s solutions and the error was still there. It was gone only when I separated two APIs and put each of them in a separate component. My question is why exactly?
I expected both APIs to work just fine alongside each other but the second one was shown as OPTION type in the network tab of the inspector.

Where is your code?

It’s a lot of code and more than a file . I think I have found the reason why separation of two useQuery solved the problem . You see two requests being called at the same time using one of the data storing systems like react-query to store the data and using similar key names was the problem I think . Changing the key names or putting them in different components so they don't render at the same time , solved the problem in my case . Still I will provide the code here . Thanks for continuing .
